# I am trying to read a text file and output it as a list of lists

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file and output it as a list of lists

text file is formatted like this

Frank Smith
5 5 0 0 100 15
Steven Jones
12 0 6 6 10 6
Barry Player
6 2 0 4 20 10
Scott Morrison
7 4 0 3 300 15
Tim Mcgrath
3 0 2 1 50 1

and I need the list imported to display like this

```
a_list = [['Frank Smith', 5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15],['Steven Jones', 12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6],['Barry Player', 6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10],['Scott Morrison', 7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15],['Tim Mcgrath', 3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1]]
```

below is what I have tried but it doesn't keep the names as a single and puts quotes on every thing

````
a_file = open("list.txt", "r")


list_of_lists = []

for line in a_file:

  stripped_line = line.strip()

  line_list = stripped_line.split()

  list_of_lists.append(line_list)


a_file.close()

print(list_of_lists)```
````

Comment: The _quotes  on every thing_ are to indicate these are strings (you should know it if you have managed to write this code). You have done a good first step in reading the lines of your file. But can you please explain, in your own words, the result you are getting and what do you think it should be done to get the result you want?

Comment: For example, why do you think the names are being splitted and not appearing as a single entity?

Comment: Show the result you're getting. Don't expect people to run your code to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code and I think there are some modifications you need to do to print in the given format.Basically What your want to print is if line is odd you just add that string to a list and if line is even you split them and convert them into a list of integer and append it to previous list This code is working fine . Kindly Check It :)

```
a_file = open("list.txt", "r")


list_of_lists = []

count = 0

index = 0

for line in a_file:
    
    if count%2 == 0:

        stripped_line = line.strip()
        if stripped_line == "":
            continue
        list_of_lists.append([stripped_line])
        
    else:
        stripped_line = line.strip()   
        line_list = stripped_line.split()
        for i in range(len(line_list)):
            line_list[i] = int(line_list[i])

        list_of_lists[index].extend(line_list)
        index+=1
    count+=1


a_file.close()

print(list_of_lists)
```

It Prints-

```
[['Frank Smith', 5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15], ['Steven Jones', 12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6], ['Barry Player', 6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10], ['Scott Morrison', 7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15], ['Tim Mcgrath', 3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1]]
```

Comment: One tiny detail: in the else block, you can do `list_of_lists[-1]` and get rid of the `index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

result = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
    row = line.split(' ')
    if len(row) == 2:
        result.append([' '.join(row)])
    else:
        row = [int(e) for e in row]
        result[-1].extend(row)

print(result)
```

prints

```
[['Frank Smith', 5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15],
 ['Steven Jones', 12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6],
 ['Barry Player', 6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10],
 ['Scott Morrison', 7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15],
 ['Tim Mcgrath', 3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1]]
```

Explanation: Read the file into a string, then separate each line of text into a separate string by splitting the string at newlines, then separate each word of the line into a separate string by splitting the line at whitespaces. If there are two words in the line, we know it is a name and add a new list to our result - which is a list of lists - containing the name as a string. Otherwise, we know that it is the numbers, and convert them from strings to integers and add them to the last list in the result.